# How to force 2 or 3 characters or digits using angularJS ui-mask

Tags: angularjs

I am using the ui-mask plugin in angularJS but cannot seem to get the ui-mask directive to work. I need to force the user to enter either 2 or 3 characters (can also be digits) in an input element.

I tried :

ui-mask="AA?"
ui-mask="**?"

Here is my markup below. I am trying to force the Initials to be 2 or 3 characters (can also be digits). The goal is for the web page to disallow additional characters i.e. stop accepting characters when the user tries to type the 4th character.

```
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="txtAccountName" class="col-md-1" style="margin: 5px; padding: 0;">User Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" ng-disabled="isEditMode" disallow-spaces class="form-control input-sm" id="txtAccountName" ng-model="currentAuthorizedUser.Username" />
            </div>
            <label for="txtInitials" class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2" style="padding: 0px;">Initials:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtInitials" ui-mask="AAA?" ng-model="currentAuthorizedUser.Initials" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: CAn you provide a demo code on plunkr.com ?

Comment: I added my markup to the question. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a regex like this: `\^[\d\w]{2}$\g`

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/fnSZbx/1

Comment: Yes but how do I use this Regex in an input mask in an angularJS web page?